# duplicates when updating MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

I'm new to MySQL and I have a list of locations to be inserted.
The schema looks like:

```
state: String
city:  String
zip:   Integer
```

But the list contains duplcates. For example, there might be multiple ("los angeles", "ca", 90007) records.

If I insert them as they are, there will be more than one records with the same location but different ids.

I know for each insert, I can query first. If it already exists, I can skip it. But it will be extremely slow. Also I want to do the insertion in a batch way but it seems quite difficult to do a query before each batch.

So How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: determine if you can go composite key. unique key (x,y,z).  Or a unique key (zipcode). Followed by an `insert ignore`

Comment: Thanks, I succeeded in avoiding duplicates by using unique key!

Comment: I hope the Stack community does not use `insert ignore` based on my comment. It really should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

As Drew suggested, I avoided the duplicates by using a unique composite key on city/state/zip combination.